# SSD installed, but shows as HDD in command output

Tags: centos, ssh, hardware, ssd

Strange issue here.

I have a 480GB SSD drive installed in this server. I installed it myself. I see it, it's there. But, I'm getting an incorrect output on a typically used command to determine if it's a hdd or ssd.

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational
1

[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/scsi/scsi
Attached devices:
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
Vendor: ATA      Model: SanDisk SDSSDHII Rev: 00RL
Type:   Direct-Access
```

Why would it show "1" instead of 0?  SanDisk SDSSDHII is correct as that's what I ordered from Amazon and installed myself. It's there, but showing 0.

I'm running Centos 6.6

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

[root@localhost ~]# uname -r
2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64
```

MORE INFO

```
/dev/sda:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

ATA device, with non-removable media
Standards:
        Likely used: 1
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       0       0
        heads           0       0
        sectors/track   0       0
        --
        Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes 
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
        IORDY not likely
        Cannot perform double-word IO
        R/W multiple sector transfer: not supported
        DMA: not supported
        PIO: pio0 



[root@localhost ~]# dmesg|grep sda
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 937703088 512-byte logical blocks: (480 GB/447 GiB)
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 67 00 00 08
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
 sda: sda1 sda2
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
dracut: Scanning devices sda2 sdb2  for LVM logical volumes Primary/lv_swap VolGroup/lv_swap Primary/lv_root 
EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
SELinux: initialized (dev sda1, type ext4), uses xattr
```

OUTPUT SMARTCTL

[root@localhost ~]# smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 5.43 2012-06-30 r3573 [x86_64-linux-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

Probable ATA device behind a SAT layer

Comment: What does `hdparm -I /dev/sda` (that's capital 'i') say? If the "Nominal Media Rotation Rate" line doesn't say "Solid State Device", it means the drive is reporting its rotation rate incorrectly.

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# hdparm -I /dev/sda
-bash: hdparm: command not found

Comment: You'd need to install the `hdparm` package then (you can remove it afterwards).

Comment: @StephenKitt updated my post with output

Comment: That is very odd indeed; the last time I saw `hdparm` report "bad/missing sense data" must have been in the late nineties... What does `dmesg|grep sda` produce?

Comment: Updated post with info

Comment: This would be a comment if it weren't for the rep system limit... What does `smartctl -a /dev/sda` tell you? That command is from the smartmontools package. It reports this for one of my SSDs: `Rotation Rate: Solid State Device`

Comment: @JosipRodin thanks, updated my post...result nothing like you showed? weird

Comment: @Bashed I get the same entry in the output as JosipRodin on my system with ssd:`Rotation Rate: Solid State Device`

Comment: @Bashed did it also suggest that you try adding `-d ata` or `-d sat` arguments to the smartctl command? Try that.